# New Custom Angular Directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a new directive to be use as a component in multiple projects. But the basic template is not even printing anything. You can check the plunker code sample and check that 'Hola' is not been printed. And there is not error in the console too.

```
angular.module('peoplewareDo.ng-Form-builder', []).directive('formBuilder', function () {
  return {
    //require: ['ngModel'],
        restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'Hola',//'ng-form-builder.html',
        scope: {
            form:'='
        }
    };
});
```

Here is my Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/UEWTgDoVlFAUychrEC9D?p=preview

Also you can check the complete project under:
https://github.com/peoplewareDo/ng-form-builder

Comment: Just reviewed your code, you can't use templateUrl to return html you should use just template: to use static html, the other error if you cant just render plain text you should encapsulate the response something like `<span>Hola</span>`,  Take a look at this fix on your plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/vuHfdwvEb7BcXfDO4lOb?p=preview

Comment: Thanks that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that `'peoplewareDo.ng-Form-builder'` should have a lowercase F.

Another problem is that you're trying to inject `$scope` into a directive. You should use `scope` inside of the link function or inject `$scope` into the directive's controller.

Comment: Nice catch, thanks; but still not working and no error on console.